# how to adding the all value from " price" node with diffrent parent in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Database Structure

[image]

I am still new with android and Firebase stuff and I have encountered a few problems when trying to adding the value from node, the thing is, I want to add all value from "price" node, but I have problem where, every price node have different parent, and I don't know how to add all value with different parent

what i've already tried:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("mycart").child(ID).child(uid).child("quantity");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
             ///...code
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To sum up all your prices from all the keys, you can do this:

```
databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("mycart").child(ID);
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        float price = 0;
        for(Datasnapshot snapshot: datasnapshot.getChildren()){
            price += snapshot.child("price").getValue(Float.class);
        }
        Log.d("Total: ", price);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});
```